# More graceful way of releasing JQM page transition lock

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm adding some exception handling into my JQM app and I'm having trouble with page transitions.

In a nutshell, I'm doing this:

```
window.onerror = function myErrorHandler(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
   // Crap, something bad happened somewhere.  
   // Tell the user about it
   // Report it to TestFlight
   // Look at the variables in memory and try to determine how to gracefully recover.
}
```

Overall it is working well - I can generally return the user to the main menu or another "safe" recovery point, instead of the app turning into a rock.

The problem is this: If the exception happens during the initialization of a page, JQM's "isPageTransitioning" flag is left as TRUE.  Thus, it won't accept any more $.mobile.changePage() calls.

There is a function in JQM called releasePageTransitionLock() that fixes the problem.  It is not exposed publically, however.

I hacked JQM by adding this method:

```
$.mobile.releasePageTransitionLock = function()
{
    releasePageTransitionLock();
}
```

Works perfect - but I'd rather not hack my JQM file.

Is there another reasonable way to access the releasePageTransitionLock() within JQM's protected environment?